# Facebook Messenger Platform: Language on facebook generated quick replies

Tags: facebook-messenger-bot

So I am building a chatbot with Facebook's messenger platform. I have come across a 'Locale/Language' issue.

When using the "Location" quick reply, Facebook uses English for the button sent to the user ('Send location').

Seeing as this chatbot is being used in French Polynesia, I need the button text to be in French.

Does anyone know how to do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, its not possible for all the standard Messenger text (like 'Menu' in Hamburger menu, Send Location etc.,). I tested it by changing the user profile locale as well.

Even sending `title` for `quick_replies` entries don't help.

Thanks
Sriram

Comment: Thanks Sriram, hopefully facebook will remedy this in the near future.